# How do I resize the magnifier/zoom window in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, accessibility, zoom

My wife lets our baby daughter play with my iPad, and something she did has caused the magnifier/zoom window (one of the accessibility features) to end up tall and narrow instead of the usual size and shape. How do I resize it so that it is more useful again?

Comment: I was going to say ask the baby, but that might not work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is:

1. Toggle the zoom
2. Locate the rounded rectangle at the bottom of the zoom window(the one you use to move the zoom window around)
   [image: Step 2]
3. Tap that once(**without dragging**) 
   [image: Step 3]
4. Tap "Resize Lens" 
   [image: Step 4]
5. Use the classic resize tools
   [image: Step 5]
6. Tap outside of the window to save the configuration.

Hope that helps!